# How to simulate long time process (sleep) in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I want to stop/sleep executing to simulate long time process, unfortunately I can't find information about it. I've read the following topic ([How can I "sleep" a Dart program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449846/how-can-i-sleep-a-dart-program)), but it isn't what I look for.

For example `sleep()` function from `dart:io` packages isn't applicable, because this package is not available in a browser.

For example:

```
import 'dart:html';
main() {
  // I want to "sleep"/hang executing during several seconds
  // and only then run the rest of function's body
  querySelect('#loading').remove();
  ...other functions and actions...
}
```

I know that there is `Timer` class to make callbacks after some time, but still it doesn't prevent the execution of program as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to stop execution. You can either use a `Timer`, `Future.delayed`, or just use an endless loop which only ends after certain time has passed.

Comment: Thanks Gunter, I like answers like this) Strict, idiomatic and simple

Answer (score 2):

If you want a stop the world sleeping function, you could do it entirely yourself. I will mention that I don't recommend you do this, it's a very bad idea to stop the world, but if you really want it:

```
void sleep(Duration duration) {
  var ms = duration.inMilliseconds;
  var start = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  while (true) {
    var current = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    if (current - start >= ms) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  print("Begin.");
  sleep(new Duration(seconds: 2));
  print("End.");
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach!) Thank you for suggestion!