# Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: ProcessUtils._sleep

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
 performTask();
}

void performTask() {
 task1();
 task2();
 task3();
}

void task1() {
 print('task1');
}

void task2() {
 Duration timeDuration = Duration(seconds: 3);
 sleep(timeDuration);
 print('task2');
}

void task3() {
 print('task3');
}
```

After executing first function that is task1() it throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: ProcessUtils._sleep
```

Comment: How are you executing this code?

Comment: online in dartpad.dev

Comment: dartpad.dev does not support "dart:io".

Comment: ok, got it .thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same roadblock! Not sure how to get sleep to work, but i found that using async/await is a bit more predictable:

```
// Unused import
// import 'dart:io'; // Delete me

void main() {
 performTask();
}

// No need for async/await here, just the method in which it's used to await Future.delayed
void performTask() {
 task1();
 task2();
 task3();
}

void task1() {
 print('task1');
}

// I'm still a bit new to flutter, but as I understand it, best practice is to use Future<T> myFunction() {...} when defining async/await method.
// In this case <T> is <void> because you're not returning anything!
Future<void> task2() async {
 Duration timeDuration = Duration(seconds: 3);
 // sleep(timeDuration) // Delete Me
 await Future.duration(timeDuration); // replacement for the sleep method, comes from the 'package:flutter/material.dart'
 print('task2');
}

void task3() {
 print('task3');
}
```

Credit: [How can I "sleep" a Dart program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449846/how-can-i-sleep-a-dart-program)

Answer (score 0):

Since Future.duration doesn't

```dart
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
```

credit: [How can I "sleep" a Dart program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449846/how-can-i-sleep-a-dart-program)