# What's _ProcessUtils in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was searching for sleep method in Flutter/Dart and I found this:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-io/sleep.html

But I can't get it to work because it errors: `Undefined name '_ProcessUtils'`

I know I can use [Future.delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449846/how-can-i-sleep-a-dart-program) or just use Animations, but I'm just curious about `_ProcessUtils`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dart` uses a leading underscore in an identifier to mark members and top-level declarations as `private`.

`_ProcessUtils` is a private class that is not accessible to you. You should not need it. It's the implementation, not an example.

Just call `sleep()` with your duration.

Read more about [Libraries and Visibility](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)

Comment: Thanks, this works on Flutter: `sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));` But it seems Dart does not have the `sleep()` function, this: `sleep(100)` does not work for example on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Comment: You would need to `import 'dart.io'` and that does not work on the web.